# Calculate leaves from joining_date on yearly basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Employee is allowed 15 leaves in year for example. My function is calculating the total leaves of allover . But I want to calculate the since joining date and when year is complete since joining date the allowed leaves is update to 15.he method which is calculating total leaves of employee.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  acts_as_paranoid
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :email, presence: true,
            format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i,
                      message: "is not valid"
                    }
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :country, presence: true, format: { with: /[a-z]+/i ,
    message: "only allows letters" }
  validates :joining_date, :bank_name, :bank_title, presence: true
  validates :current_salary, :allowed_leaves, numericality: true, presence: true
  validates :bank_account_id, uniqueness:true, numericality: true, presence: true, length: { minimum: 16, maximum: 16}
  has_many :increments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :salaries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :leaves, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :designations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :employee_projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :employee_projects
  has_many :timelogs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :medical_applications, dependent: :destroy
  before_update :update_leaves, :if => :allowed_leaves_changed?
  
  def display_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end

  def self.send_and_create_salary_slips
    send_salary_slips
  end

  def update_leaves
    taken_leaves = self.leaves.where(status: "Approved").count
    allowed_leaves = self.allowed_leaves
    total_leaves = (allowed_leaves-taken_leaves)
    self.update_column(:availed_leaves, total_leaves) 
  end

  def create_salary_slip
    salary = self.salaries.new
    salary.gross_salary = self.current_salary
    salary.basic_salary = self.current_salary
    salary.month = Date.today.month
    salary.year = Date.today.year
    salary.status = "pending"
    salary.save!
  end

  def self.send_salary_slips
    self.all.each do |employee|
      salary_slip = employee.salaries.last
      EmployeeMailer.send_salary_slip(salary_slip, employee).deliver if salary_slip.present?

      employee.create_salary_slip
    end
  end
end
```

THe leave model is hear

```
class Leave < ApplicationRecord
  PENDING = "Pending"
  Approved = "Approved"
  REJECTED = "Rejected"

  belongs_to :employee
  before_save :save_status
  after_update :calculate_availed_leave
  validates :leave_date, :leave_description, presence: true

  def allowed?
    self.employee.availed_leaves > 0
  end

  def display_status
    {
      PENDING => "Pending",
      Approved => "Approved",
      REJECTED => "Rejected",
    }[status.to_s]
  end

  def Approved?
    status == Approved
  end

  def REJECTED?
    status == REJECTED
  end

  private

  def save_status
    self.status ||= "Pending" # note self.status = 'P' if self.status.nil? might be safer (per @frontendbeauty)
  end

  def calculate_availed_leave
    date = self.employee.joining_date + 1.year
    apply_date = self.leave_date
    if apply_date < date
      taken_leaves = self.employee.leaves.where(status: "Approved").count
      availed_leaves = self.employee.allowed_leaves - taken_leaves
      self.employee.update(availed_leaves: availed_leaves)
    elsif apply_date < new_date
      allowed_leaves = self.employee.allowed_leaves
      self.employee.update(availed_leaves: allowed_leaves)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: Is the allowed leaves pro-rated?  Which is to say, at his 4 month anniversary is he allowed to take 5 days? Or is he only allowed to take his 15 days leave after his anniversary date? At his joining date + 1.year + 1.day would he have 30 days to take or only 15?

Comment: Employee  only allowed to take his 15 days leave after his anniversary date

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I am calculating the leave from joining date to when year is completed.when year is completed employee leaves start again from 15 . If employee applied 15 leaves in year then it is not allowed to apply for leaves

Comment: Can he carry over?  Which is to say if in the last year he only took 12, on his anniversary does he have 15 to take or 18?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn No every Year he have 15 to take

Comment: Where does this method live?  Is it a method in the `Leave` class? Can you post the `Leave` class and the `Employee` class in your question?

Comment: The method leave in leave model

Comment: @SteveTurczyn i posted the employee classs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting the additional information. I now see that the method is an `after_update` to update the total and available leave in the `employees` table.

It's not clear how long you'll be keeping leave records on the system, but if you don't have specific plans to purge records you need to ensure that you don't update the employee's available dates when you re-save a leave record that's, say, three years old.

I also note you're storing the remaining available leave in the employee record, which means there's a chance it can become incorrect.  I think it's better to calculate as needed.

So, I'd add the following methods to the Employee record.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord

  def allocated_leave_days(date=nil)
    date ||= Date.today
    date > joining_date + 1.year ? 15 : 0
  end

  def year_to_examine(date=nil)
    date ||= Date.today
    end_date = joining_date
    end_date = end_date + 1.year while end_date < date
    start_date = [joining_date, end_date - 1.year].max
    (start_date..end_date)
  end

  def taken_leave_days(date=nil)
    date ||= Date.today
    leaves.where(status: 'Approved', leave_date: year_to_examine(date)).count
  end

  def remaining_leave_days(date=nil)
    date ||= Date.today
    [allocated_leave_days(date) - taken_leave_days(date), 0].max
  end

end
```

So, now, if you want to know the employee's entitlement today, you would do `my_employee.allocated_leave_days` or (for some date in the future or past) `my_employee.allocated_leave_days(my_test_date)`

If you want to know how many days he has remaining, you would do `my_employee.remaining_leave_days` or (for some date in a future year) `my_employee.remaining_leave_days(my_test_date)`

Comment: sir the employee current year leave is completed for this year when i am selecting the date after year of  of joining_date it is still not applying for leave

Comment: Which of the methods is not working?  I'm not clear what you're saying.

Comment: @ SteveTurczyn when year is completed employee leaves start again from 15 . But the above method is not starting from 15 again .when Employee leaves completed then allowed leave start again from 15

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "above method"... I gave you four methods.  If the date you're interested in is greater than join_date + 1.year then `allocated_leave_days` always returns 15. The `taken_leve_days` always returns the actual approved leaves for the employee's current year.  The `remaining_leave_days` gives you the difference between the two.  You have to be clearer in your questions.  `